# Can you include additional header files in an active gdb session?

Tags: c++, gdb

I am debugging something and would like to use `typeid` in the `typeinfo` header file. I am coming from a beginner Python background using `pdb` where you could `import` a library and test things while in the session.

Is it possible to include extra header files in a running `gdb` session [specifically those in the `std` library] or is including the headers [say `typeinfo`] before compilation the only way?

Answer (score 0):

`typeid` is not a header file, it is an operator, referring to an object of the polymorphic type `const std::type_info` or of some type derived from it. See [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid).

You can call it during debug session and see it's return value without any additional steps like importing a library. See example debug session for a test program:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  int a = 1;
  double b = 2;

  std::cout << a << std::endl; 
  std::cout << b << std::endl; 

  return 0;
}
```

```
$ gdb -q ./a.out 
Reading symbols from ./a.out...
(gdb) start
Temporary breakpoint 1 at 0x40118e: file t1.cpp, line 4.

Temporary breakpoint 1, main () at t1.cpp:4
4     int a = 1;
(gdb) n
5     double b = 2;
(gdb) 
7     std::cout << a << std::endl; 
(gdb) p typeid(a)
$1 = {_vptr.type_info = 0x7ffff7f81340 <vtable for __cxxabiv1::__fundamental_type_info+16>, __name = 0x7ffff7f2f654 <typeinfo name for int> "i"}
(gdb) p typeid(b)
$2 = {_vptr.type_info = 0x7ffff7f81340 <vtable for __cxxabiv1::__fundamental_type_info+16>, __name = 0x7ffff7f2f693 <typeinfo name for double> "d"}
```